# data manipulation using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

i am working on data manipulation using sqlite.
how can i insert the datetime value in sqlite
i implemented the below code in my app.
it works,

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dateObj = null;
dateObj =curFormater.parse(txt_date_start.getText().toString());
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
```

but I want to store as "2011-Jul-13 05:15 PM",ple give me example..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in sqlite you dont have any  data type as date or time.while creating the column u have to specify any one of the text,int or real data type.then while inserting make use of the date and time funcs of sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Create column in sqlite's table with type TIMESTAMP/DATE and put the date in UNIX timestamp.